# SQL query to create feed file with special format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create a sql query to create a feed file, my issue is that the file have a header and detail. The studen ID is the header and the classes are the detail

```
Select st.student_id, st.academics_year, st.academic_term, cl.class, cl.schedule, cl.days
from student_term st
left join on classes cl on cl.year = st.academic_year and cl.term=st.academics_term
```

My query results :

```
12345 2022 spring mat01, 08:00 to 09:00 TW
12345 2022 spring fin101, 10:00 to 11:00 MF
12345 2022 spring bio101, 14:00 to 15:00 MF
```

What I need :

```
12345
mat01, 08:00 to 09:00 TW
fin101, 10:00 to 11:00 MF
bio101, 14:00 to 15:00 MF

    result
seq type  linetex
1    0    12345
1    0    45678
1    0    98765
1    1    mat131  08:00 to 09:00
1    1    lit131  08:00 to 09:00
1    1    bio131  09:00 to 10:00
```

Comment: This sort of file formatting/layout work is normally done by the client app/presentation layer (not rdbms:sql) but it is possible to get SQL return result rows very close to this. It would help if you tag the actual rdbms you are using. Also why did you SELECT acedemics_year & term in the query if you didn't need it in the results?

Comment: tinazmu. I select academic year and term just for me, to make sure all student below to year & term. I am working with Microsoft SQL Server. Thank you!

Comment: This may be of help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#group-by-rollup

Comment: All rows in a result set MUST have the same columns.

Comment: @Tinazmu, thank you for all your help I cannot paste the code it said my edit cannot be submitted, is the same code im using, when I found that when I query just for one student it works im getting the format